# $\left [(A- \langle A \rangle ),\right (B- \langle B \rangle )]=\left [A,B \right ] $

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

Let A,B two hermitian operator 
I don't grasp one of the last step of the proof of Uncertainty principle.
Why:
$$\left [(A- \langle A \rangle ),\right (B- \langle B \rangle )]=\left [A,B \right ] $$
I'm stucked here:
$$\left [(A- \langle A \rangle ),\right (B- \langle B \rangle )]=\left [AB-A\langle B \rangle - \langle A \rangle B + \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle \right] $$

Comment: Scalars, like $\langle A\rangle$ and $\langle B\rangle$, commute with everything.

Answer (score 1):

A commutator does not see scalar perturbations (or, more generally, perturbations by operators that commute with the operators involved). Concretely, if $J,K$ commute with $A$ and $B$ respectively, and between themselves, 
\begin{align}
[A+K,B+J]&=(A+K)(B+J)-(B+J)(A+K)\\ \ \\
&=AB-BA+AJ+KB+KJ-BK-JA-JK\\ \ \\
&=AB-BA=[A,B].
\end{align}